# What are "the correct spin operators" mentioned in the book "Quantum Field Theory" by Lewis H. Ryder?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin

In subchapter $2.7$ ("The relevance of the Poincaré group", page 63), to be found in [this](https://www.scribd.com/doc/195982012/Ryder-L-H-Quantum-field-theory-2ed-pdf) link, Ryder writes:

> The correct spin operators are rather complicated in form and the interested reader is referred to literature (F.Gürsey in C. DeWitt & M. Jacob (eds.), ref(9), 1965).

Now, I tried hard (but maybe not hard enough) to find the "correct spin operators" but couldn't find them anywhere. What **are** the correct spin operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fair to send you to some more available literature. Section 4.15.3 from Kleinert, S. - Particles and Quantum Fields (2016) which starts on page 345 and ends on page 347 with the relation (4.782).

With $S^{i}_{R}$ the spin 3-vector in the rest-frame, and $\hat{W}^{i} := \frac{\hat{S}^i}{Mc}$ the Wigner spin operators, we have:

[image]

The exact form of the spin operator for a representation of positive mass is given on page 280 of BLOT 1990 (Bogolubov et al. - General Principles of Quantum Field Theory, Kluwer, 1990) and it is:

$$S^j = \frac{1}{m}\left(P^0 M^j - \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{jkl} P^{k} N^{l} - P^j \frac{\vec{P}\cdot\vec{M}}{m+P^0}\right) $$

where $P^{\mu}, M^{\mu\nu}$ are the 10 generators of the Poincaré group and $N^i = M^{0i}$ and $M^i = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ijk}M^{jk}$

Comment: I only have access to Bogoliubov & Shirkov, Introduction to the Theory of Quantized Fields, 3d edition. These books should overlap, do you know the page number in this one?

Comment: @my2cts Sorry, the books are not too related. The B&S textbook does not contain the representation theory of the Poincaré group

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps you can reproduce the formulas here or maybe do you have another link?

Comment: @my2cts just added it,